# Mac OS: How can I launch the iTerm terminal, with a specific profile, from Automator or AppleScript?

Tags: macos, applescript, automator

I'm trying to assign a global keyboard shortcut that will launch a new window of iTerm, with a specific profile. (I managed to do this to launch a new Chrome window with Automator and AppleScript, but this is proving more difficult)

This would be equivalent to activating iTerm, and in the top menu select Profiles -> "my profile", with "alt" or "option" pressed, so it'll open in a new window, not a new tab in the current window.

Any ideas how to do this with either Automator or AppleScript?

In case it's relevant, I have Mac OS Mountain Lion

(Sorry if this is an absolute noob question, I just moved from Windows to Mac, and I'm trying to optimize the things I do all the time)

Thank you!

Comment: If you're new to OS X, why not give Terminal a try first? It's pretty good.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The previous answer no longer works on the latest version of iTerm2 (3), since `terminal` has been discontinued.  The new approach is to use `create window with profile`.

However, this doesn't work as expected: while if iTerm is running, it will open the new window using the appropriate profile.  But if iTerm is not running, it will open a window using the default profile, and then it will open the second window with the supplied other profile.  I came up with the following script to address this:

```
-- this script will start/activate iTerm (close the default window if the app had been newly started), then open a new session with a desired profile

on is_running(appName)
    tell application "System Events" to (name of processes) contains appName
end is_running

set iTermRunning to is_running("iTerm2")

tell application "iTerm"
    activate
    if not (iTermRunning) then
        delay 0.5
        close the current window
    end if
    create window with profile "xxxxxx"
end tell
```

Of course, it would have been really easy if iTerm supported command line parameters.  Hopefully it will [at some point](https://gitlab.com/gnachman/iterm2/issues/2095).

Answer (score 3):

Combining lines 11 and 58 of the [AppleScript sample code on the iTerm website...](http://iterm.sourceforge.net/scripting.shtml)

```
tell application "iTerm"
activate
tell (make new terminal)
    launch session "Your Profile Name"
end tell
end tell
```

Comment: Awesome! That's EXACTLY what I needed. Thank you!!

Comment: I'd love to see another answer that launches an new iTerm process, not a window in the existing app.

Comment: @Sparr: You're usually running no user application multiple times on OS X. Some behave very weirdly (or break), others actively prevent it. Is there a real reason you're looking for this?

Comment: @DanielBeck because I want the OS to behave as if it's another application, the same way it does with Fluid web apps.

Comment: "The variable terminal is not defined" (on Sonoma, but I am a n00b so may be doing it wrong)

Answer (score 0):

Based on answers above and others on `osascript` command:

From BASH command line by wrapping the AppleScript in `osascript`

```
osascript -e "tell application \"iTerm\"
    create window with profile \"my-cool-profile\"
end tell"
```

or BASH function that take a profile name as an argument:

```
open-with () {
  osascript -e "tell application \"iTerm\"
    create window with profile \"$1\"
  end tell"
}
```

As an `open-with` BASH script like `open-with my-cool-profile`

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash

PROFILE="${1-Default}"

osascript -e $"tell application \"iTerm\"
  create window with profile \"$PROFILE\"
end tell"
```

And as an `open-run` BASH script that can run a program/command for you on open:

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash

PROFILE="${1-Default}"
CMD="${2-echo "I, \$(whoami), am here at \$PWD"}"

osascript -e "tell application \"iTerm\"
  set newWindow to (create window with profile \"$PROFILE\")
  tell current session of newWindow
    write text \"$CMD\"
  end tell
end tell"
```

Example: Open in a specific profile and run ssh command

`open-run my-ssh-profile 'ssh mike@mycoolserver.com'`

Example: Open `htop` in it's own window, auto-close window when user exits `htop`

`open-run my-htop-profile 'htop && exit'`

Example: like above on a remote server via ssh

`open-run my-htop-profile 'ssh -t mike@mycoolserver.com bash -c htop && exit'`

The escaping and quoting can get pretty crazy but it does what I need