# iTerm2 profile as an "app"

Tags: iterm2

I have recently created a profile that opens nvim automatically, which works fine. However, is it possible to export it to a file/app so I can open nvim straight by double-clicking/quicksilver/spotlight?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The AppleScript for iTerm 2.9/3

```
tell application "iTerm"
    activate
    tell (create window with profile "nvim")
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: @leandros is this usable for u?

Comment: That works, no I just have to figure out how to actually write commands into the console. `write text` doesn't seem to work, neither does `execute command`.

Comment: Got it working. `tell current session of current window write text "echo test;" end tell` works like a charm. Taken from the iTerm2 AppleScript test sources. https://github.com/gnachman/iTerm2/blob/master/sources/AppleScriptTest.m

Comment: congratulations (:

Answer (score 1):

You can make an AppleScript that accomplishes this, and export that as an app.

The AppleScript [[source](https://superuser.com/a/455936)]:

```
tell application "iTerm"
activate
tell (make new terminal)
    launch session "Your Profile Name"
end tell
end tell
```

To export as app [[source](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/8299/how-do-i-make-an-applescript-file-into-a-mac-app)]:

> In Applescript editor File->Save As and choose File Format as Application.

Comment: getting this `error "The variable terminal is not defined." number -2753 from "terminal"` in 10.10 Yosemite (iterm2 2.9) LOLOL

Comment: `tell application "iTerm"
activate
create new window with profile "nvim"
end tell`
works tho

Comment: @Jeffrey04 That doesn't work, either. Neither are the examples from iTerm or anything else I tried. Any ideas?

Comment: @leandros I have posted the one I use currently for iTerm2.9/3